# Parsing copyright holder information with a regex

Tags: regex

I'm looking to parse out the copyright holder and 'Inc' if present from copyright comments of various screwed up formats. I have a regex that's working if the copyright contains a date, but I'm struggling to come up with something that can handle both situations.

Here's a few samples:

```
#   Copyright:: 2013-2016 MyCorp, Inc.
#   Copyright:: 2013-2016 MyCorp Inc.
#   Copyright:: 2013-2016 MyCorp Inc.
#   Copyright:: 2009-2010 2013-2016 MyCorp Inc.
#   Copyright:: MyCorp Inc.
#   Copyright:: John Doe
```

Here's what I was using for copyrights containing dates and the Inc. Any suggestions on how to optionally match 'Inc' while ignoring the surrounding , and . if present.

```
[0-9]{4}(?!.*[0-9]{4})(.*)(?:,)? (Inc)(?:.)?
```

Comment: In the last example, would you want to match John Doe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to be getting pretty good mileage from a simple regex which doesn't even use lookaheads:

```
^#   Copyright::(?: (?:\d{4}-\d{4}))* (.*)$
```

This will match everything which comes after the optional year range, should it occur.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101